# A question on completeness condition from Ahlfors' book

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, real-numbers, supremum-and-infimum

I'm sorry I can't think of any better title for this question. Anyways my question is : In Lars Ahlfors-Complex Analysis , the author said that Real Field satisfies completeness condition . He said , for an increasing and bounded sequence : α<sub>1</sub><α<sub>2</sub><α<sub>3</sub>....<α<sub>n</sub>... and where an assumed real number B is bigger than αn for all n , there will exist a number A=limit of α<sub>n</sub> when n tends to infinity with a special property : given any e > 0 there will exist a natural number n<sub>0</sub> such that A - e < α<sub>n</sub> < A for all n >n<sub>o</sub>. I don't understand this . To be specific , my questions are -

1. Why did he leave the sequence without terminating ? Couldn't he write the equation like this :α<sub>1</sub><α<sub>2</sub><α<sub>3</sub>....<α<sub>n</sub>...**<B** ? Or is **B** an arbitrary number from the real field which is not part of the sequence ?
2. And why do I need n to be near infinity ? I could take a quite small sequence where n is countable ..right? Then shouldn't I write : A - e < α<sub>n</sub> **≤ A** ?

   Thanks for your time.

   **Edit:** Off topic question : x<sup>2</sup>+1=0 has no roots in Real Field because of Order Relation as far as I understood . But in Complex Field there exists two roots for the equation . So does the complex field have Order Relation?

Comment: To answer your last question, no. More precisely, you could define an order on the complex numbers, but it wouldn't play nicely with the field operations

Comment: By the way, if you plan to spend much time on this site, it would be good to learn how to format mathematics here, how to get $x^2+1$ instead of x2+1 for example. There is help available via the Help menu. or https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks for the help and I edited my question

Comment: @GerryMyerson I'm new to Complex Analysis . So my question might seem silly . I didn't understand your first comment . As far as I knew, because of order relation, we say 2>1 ..right? similarly can't we say (1+2i)>(1+i) ?

Comment: Sequences don't need any *terminating*. They didn't need it in calculus/real analysis. And don't need it here. Also $n$ is always finite (but the sequence has countably infinitely many entries). May be you should review basic concepts on real sequences before diving into Ahlfors?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think Ahlfor said the sequence is bounded . So it has an end . Right? And yeah I also felt that I'll have to learn sequences  , thanks for the advice .

Comment: No. *Bounded* has a technical meaning. Don't remember whether Ahlfors reviewed it or whether he assumes that the readers know that stuff from real analysis. Anyway, here *bounded* means that a bound like that number $B$ exists.

Comment: No, we can't say $1+2i>1+i$. If we did, we'd also have to say $2i>i$, and $i>0$, so $i^2>0$, so $-1>0$, and we don't want to say that. Also, we'd have to decide which is bigger, $1+2i$ or $2+i$, and how do you propose to do that? The formal definition of an order is a set $P$, closed under multiplication, such that every element satisfies exactly one of "$x$ is in $P$", "$x=0$", or "$-x$ is in $P$". There's no such set $P$ that works for the complex numbers.

Comment: And you edited the $x^2+1$ but not using MathJax, so it still looks ugly, and you didn't edit $a_1<a_2<a_3<\cdots$ or anything else. Please, read up on that math.meta link I gave you.

Comment: Any thoughts on the comments, or on Martin's answer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson as I don't have any experience with Real Analysis , Complex Analysis sure is tough . I'll let you know whenever I'll not be able to google my way out .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, a sequence $\alpha_n$ is called *bounded* (from above) if there is a constant $C$ such that $\alpha_n\le C$ for every $n$.

To your question 1: The notation is a matter of style. However, $B$ cannot be an element of $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots\}$, because the sequence is strictly increasing and thus every $\alpha_n$ is necessarily strictly smaller than $B$ (for if $B\le\alpha_{n_0}$ for some $n_0$, then $B<\alpha_n$ for every $n>n_0$, contradicting the definition of convergence).

Your question 2 makes no sense: Of course, $n$ is taken from a countable set, namely from the set of natural numbers (this is tacitly understood by the term “sequence”). But the other part of the question has nothing to do with countability: It is not possible to have $B-\varepsilon<\alpha_1\le B$ for every $\varepsilon>0$ (unless $\alpha_1=B$), and similarly, for any other fixed $n$, it is not possible to have $B-\varepsilon<\alpha_n\le B$ for every $\varepsilon>0$. On the other hand, if $B$ was chosen “correctly” (recall that completeness of $\mathbb R$ means that such a choice is possible), then for every $\varepsilon>0$ there **does** exist some $n$ such that $B-\varepsilon<\alpha_n\le B$. Necessarily, the smaller you choose $\varepsilon>0$, the larger $n$ has to be, because $\alpha_1<\alpha_2<\ldots$.

Note also, that completeness of $\mathbb R$ does not only mean that the limit $B$ exists for **some** bounded increasing sequence, but actually that **every** such sequence has a limit. To get a feeling that this is a non-trivial property, consider the particular sequence $\alpha_1=1$, $\alpha_2=1+\frac1{2^2}$, $\alpha_3=1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}$, $\ldots$, $\alpha_n=1+\frac1{2^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}$ and the similar sequence $\beta_n=1+\frac1{2^3}+\cdots+\frac1{n^3}$. It can be shown that both sequences are bounded from above. Hence, the completeness of $\mathbb R$ implies that they converge to some limit. For the first sequence, Euler has shown that the limit is $\frac{\pi^2}6$ ([Basel problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem)) (BTW, by implicitly using complex analysis), but about the limit $B$ of the second sequence still almost nothing is known (a relatively new famous result about this particular limit is that it is an irrational number, and one can get some numerical estimates, but that's it, essentially). Anyway, although we cannot calculate the limit yet (and maybe we will never be able to), we know at least that the limit does exist, because $\mathbb R$ is complete.

That being said, I would recommend that you read a text book on real analysis where all such things are well explained before you start with a text book on (advanced) complex analysis. I am sure you will need such basics from real analysis in much more places on this book. Moreover, the book of Ahlfors is somewhat aged meanwhile. This does not mean that there is something wrong with it, but it is likely that some notations are hardly used anymore which might confuse you when you eventually read a more modern treatment of complex analysis. (Though knowing older notations can sometimes also be an advantage, but you should be aware of it.)